# xkeyval Error: `refsegment:00' undefined with biber and biblatex

Tags: biblatex, subdividing

I'm trying to deel with a bibliography by section in book document. I grope, but I can not seem to correct this error :

```
    ! Package keyval Error: refsegment:00 undefined.

See the keyval package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.45 ...[refsegment:\therefsection \therefsegment]
```

I'm using biber 1.9 en texlive 2014.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}

% Paquets additionnels
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{newunicodechar} %pour les caractères speciaux dans les biblio par exemple!
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00A0}{~} %permet d'accèpter les problèmes d'espaces insécable
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00A0}{ }

%\hyphenpenalty 10000 %evite de couper les mots
% Définition du type de la bibliographie
%\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[
  %refsegment=chapter,
  %refsegment=part,
  maxcitenames=2,
  maxbibnames=99,
  style=authoryear-comp,
  backend=biber,  
  doi=true, 
  url=false, 
  eprint=false, 
  hyperref=true,
  firstinits=true,
  uniquename=init
]{biblatex}

%definit un biblio en temps que chapitre 
\defbibheading{bibliography}[\bibname]{\section*{#1}}
\addbibresource{exemple_overflow.bib}

\begin{document}
\section{ acidityGIS : la coopérative comme levier d'adaptation}
\subsection{Introduction}
Le changement climatique serait donc une contrainte forte  qui viendrait s'ajouter à celles qui pesent déjà sur la viticulture \autocite{jones_climate_2005, nemani_asymmetric_2001,  white_extreme_2006}. 
Les enjeux deviennent donc de plus en plus pressant, et des controverses apparaissent quand aux devenir de la viticulture (\textcite{hannah_climate_2013} \textsc{vs} \textcite{van_leeuwen_why_2013}). Si le changement climatique n'est pas contesté, ce sont les capacités des viticulteurs à tirer profit de leur environnement et de pratique cultural qui sont encore aujourd'hui à explorer. \\
\section{Modelisation empirique}
Un ensemble de travaux abordent ces questions sous des aspects aussi divers que  : la génétique et la phénologie de la vigne \autocite{duchene_towards_2012}, les aspects sociaux \autocite{viguie_viticulture_2014}, des pratiques culturales \autocite{herrero-langreo_mapping_2013} ou encore sous l'angle climatologique et spatial \autocite{moriondo_projected_2013, quenol_multi-scale_2014, briche_critical_2014}. Dans ce papier nous proposons de nous intéresser à cette question sous l'angle de la modélisation multi-agent.

\printbibliography[refsegment:\therefsection \therefsegment]
\end{document}
```

my exemple_overflow.bib file is :

```
@article{van_leeuwen_why_2013,
    title = {Why climate change will not dramatically decrease viticultural suitability in main wine-producing areas by 2050},
    volume = {110},
    issn = {0027-8424, 1091-6490},
    url = {http://www.pnas.org/content/110/33/E3051},
    doi = {10.1073/pnas.1307927110},
    pages = {E3051--E3052},
    number = {33},
    journaltitle = {Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences},
    shortjournal = {{PNAS}},
    author = {Van Leeuwen, Cornelis and Schultz, Hans R. and Cortazar-Atauri, Iñaki Garcia de and Duchêne, Eric and Ollat, Nathalie and Pieri, Philippe and Bois, Benjamin and Goutouly, Jean-Pascal and Quénol, Hervé and Touzard, Jean-Marc and Malheiro, Aureliano C. and Bavaresco, Luigi and Delrot, Serge},
    urldate = {2014-08-28},
    date = {2013-08-13},
    langid = {english},
    pmid = {23792579}
}

@article{moriondo_projected_2013,
    title = {Projected shifts of wine regions in response to climate change},
    volume = {119},
    issn = {0165-0009, 1573-1480},
    url = {http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10584-013-0739-y},
    doi = {10.1007/s10584-013-0739-y},
    pages = {825--839},
    number = {3},
    journaltitle = {Climatic Change},
    shortjournal = {Climatic Change},
    author = {Moriondo, M. and Jones, G. V. and Bois, B. and Dibari, C. and Ferrise, R. and Trombi, G. and Bindi, M.},
    urldate = {2014-08-28},
    date = {2013-08-01},
    langid = {english},
    keywords = {Atmospheric Sciences, Climate Change Impacts}
}

@article{white_extreme_2006,
    title = {Extreme heat reduces and shifts United States premium wine production in the 21st century},
    volume = {103},
    url = {http://www.pnas.org/content/103/30/11217.short},
    pages = {11217--11222},
    number = {30},
    journaltitle = {Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences},
    author = {White, Michael A. and Diffenbaugh, N. S. and Jones, Gregory V. and Pal, J. S. and Giorgi, F.},
    urldate = {2014-08-28},
    date = {2006}
}

@article{nemani_asymmetric_2001,
    title = {Asymmetric warming over coastal California and its impact on the premium wine industry},
    volume = {19},
    url = {https://secure.ntsg.umt.edu/publications/2001/NWCJRCP01/cres19_wine_nemani_2001.pdf},
    pages = {25--34},
    number = {1},
    journaltitle = {Climate research},
    author = {Nemani, Ramakrishna R. and White, Michael A. and Cayan, Daniel R. and Jones, Gregory V. and Running, Steven W. and Coughlan, Joseph C. and Peterson, David L.},
    urldate = {2014-08-28},
    date = {2001}
}

@article{hannah_climate_2013,
    title = {Climate change, wine, and conservation},
    volume = {110},
    issn = {0027-8424, 1091-6490},
    url = {http://www.pnas.org/content/110/17/6907},
    doi = {10.1073/pnas.1210127110},
    pages = {6907--6912},
    number = {17},
    journaltitle = {Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences},
    shortjournal = {{PNAS}},
    author = {Hannah, Lee and Roehrdanz, Patrick R. and Ikegami, Makihiko and Shepard, Anderson V. and Shaw, M. Rebecca and Tabor, Gary and Zhi, Lu and Marquet, Pablo A. and Hijmans, Robert J.},
    urldate = {2014-08-28},
    date = {2013-04-23},
    langid = {english},
    pmid = {23569231}
}

@article{jones_climate_2005,
    title = {Climate Change and Global Wine Quality},
    volume = {73},
    issn = {0165-0009, 1573-1480},
    url = {http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10584-005-4704-2},
    doi = {10.1007/s10584-005-4704-2},
    pages = {319--343},
    number = {3},
    journaltitle = {Climatic Change},
    shortjournal = {Climatic Change},
    author = {Jones, Gregory V. and White, Michael A. and Cooper, Owen R. and Storchmann, Karl},
    urldate = {2014-08-28},
    date = {2005-12-01},
    langid = {english},
    keywords = {Meteorology/Climatology}
}

@article{herrero-langreo_mapping_2013,
    title = {Mapping Grapevine (Vitis vinifera L.) Water Status during the Season Using Carbon Isotope Ratio (δ13C) as Ancillary Data},
    volume = {64},
    issn = {0002-9254,},
    url = {http://www.ajevonline.org/content/64/3/307},
    doi = {10.5344/ajev.2013.12125},
    pages = {307--315},
    number = {3},
    journaltitle = {American Journal of Enology and Viticulture},
    shortjournal = {Am. J. Enol. Vitic.},
    author = {Herrero-Langreo, Ana and Tisseyre, Bruno and Goutouly, Jean-Pascal and Scholasch, Thibaut and Leeuwen, Cornelis van},
    urldate = {2014-08-29},
    date = {2013-01-09},
    langid = {english}
}

@article{quenol_multi-scale_2014,
    title = {A multi-scale climatic analysis of viticultural terroirs in the context of climate change : the "{TERADCLIM}" project},
    url = {http://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01018092},
    shorttitle = {A multi-scale climatic analysis of viticultural terroirs in the context of climate change},
    pages = {23--32},
    journaltitle = {International Journal of Vine and Wine Sciences},
    author = {Quénol, Hervé and Bonnardot, Valérie},
    urldate = {2014-08-29},
    date = {2014}
}

@article{duchene_towards_2012,
    title = {Towards the adaptation of grapevine varieties to climate change: {QTLs} and candidate genes for developmental stages},
    volume = {124},
    issn = {1432-2242},
    doi = {10.1007/s00122-011-1734-1},
    shorttitle = {Towards the adaptation of grapevine varieties to climate change},
    pages = {623--635},
    number = {4},
    journaltitle = {{TAG}. Theoretical and applied genetics. Theoretische und angewandte Genetik},
    shortjournal = {Theor. Appl. Genet.},
    author = {Duchêne, Eric and Butterlin, Gisèle and Dumas, Vincent and Merdinoglu, Didier},
    date = {2012-03},
    pmid = {22052019},
    keywords = {Acclimatization, Chromosome Mapping, Chromosomes, Plant, Climate change, Crosses, Genetic, Fruit, Genes, Plant, Genotype, Microsatellite Repeats, Phenotype, Quantitative Trait Loci, Vitis}
}

@article{briche_critical_2014,
    title = {Critical analysis of simulated daily temperature data from the {ARPEGE}-climate model: application to climate change in the Champagne wine-producing region},
    volume = {123},
    issn = {0165-0009, 1573-1480},
    url = {http://hal.univ-brest.fr/hal-00931867/},
    doi = {10.1007/s10584-013-1044-5},
    shorttitle = {Critical analysis of simulated daily temperature data from the {ARPEGE}-climate model},
    pages = {241--254},
    number = {2},
    journaltitle = {Climatic Change},
    author = {Briche, E. and Beltrando, G. and Somot, S. and Quenol, H.},
    urldate = {2014-08-29},
    date = {2014-03},
    langid = {english}
}

@article{viguie_viticulture_2014,
    title = {Viticulture and Adaptation to Climate Change},
    url = {http://hal-enpc.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00982086},
    pages = {55--60},
    journaltitle = {Journal International des Sciences de la Vigne et du Vin},
    author = {Viguié, Vincent and Lecocq, Franck and Touzard, Jean-Marc},
    urldate = {2014-08-29},
    date = {2014}
}
```

and the result

[image]

any leads are welcome !

E.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a truly minimal (but compilable) working example (that shows the error)? A lost of stuff you seem to include in your MWE is not related to the problem at all and you could probably easily get rid of all the `\input`s and just have one compact example.

Comment: The correct syntax would be `\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment]` instead of `\printbibliography[refsegment:\therefsection \therefsegment]` (I'm not sure why the `\therefsection` comes in here at all, it does not seem to play a role anywhere else).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a misuse of the `biblatex`-`keyval` optional argument syntax to `\printbibliography`.

Comment: I don't completely agree, I have truly made a misunderstanding but this can help other to understand segmentation work.